# How to disable bottom panel/message tray in Gnome Shell 3.4?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, panel, gnome-shell-extension, messaging-tray

Running **Ubuntu 12.04** with **Gnome Shell 3.4**. After enabling Bottom panel extension (to remove annoying Message tray/bottom panel/hot-corner at the bottom; You know what I am talking about(: ), still a "half" message pop-up after adding USB drive. Well, sorry, dont know how to explain it correctly. Maybe someone have any clue how to solve this thing and get rid of that?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sounds to me you should report that to the developer. I guess you are talking about [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/).

Comment: No. It is for Linux Mint Gnome Shell extensions (mgse). Checked my sources - it is a PPA from webupd8 for Ubuntu Oneiric. So, I guess this could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/393/distraction-free/) extension may help you. Check out other extensions for Gnome shell [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/)